# Invalid value at position X [object Object]' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on a JavaScript application that creates heatmaps using the Google Visualization API, but for some reason whenever I add my array of data to the heatmap the 2nd to last element always throws this error:

```
Invalid value at position X [object Object]' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]
```

Can anyone explain this error to me? I have never seen it before and my search of SO and Google turned up nothing useful.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var heatMapOptions =
    {
            data: weightedLocations,
            dissipating: false,
            map: this.googleMap,
            gradient: [
                      'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',       //black - transparent
                      'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',     //blue
                      'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',   //cyan
                      'rgba(0, 238, 0, 1)',     //green
                      'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',     //lime-green
                      'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',   //yellow
                      'rgba(255, 165, 0, 1)',   //orange
                      'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',     //red
                      'rgba(139, 0, 0, 1)'      //dark-red
                    ],
            maxIntensity: 150,
            opacity: 0.6,
            radius: 4 //4 pixels
    };

    //create a Heatmap overlay to sit on top of the google map, passing it the initialization object created above
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({ options: heatMapOptions});
```

**Where the object is created**

```
function Box(inBox, count)
{
    var box = inBox.toString();
    //strip off any sort keys if they exist
    if(box.indexOf("~") >= 0) {
        box = box.substr(0, box.indexOf('~'));
    }

    //split box into box number and coordinates of four corners
    var splitBox  = box.split("_");
    //console.log(splitBox);

    var boxNumber = splitBox[0];

    this.boxNumber = boxNumber.replace("count|", "");
    this.swlatlon = new google.maps.LatLng( splitBox[1], splitBox[2]);    // a Google LatLng object
    this.selatlon = new google.maps.LatLng( splitBox[3], splitBox[4]);    // a Google LatLng object
    this.nwlatlon = new google.maps.LatLng( splitBox[5], splitBox[6]);    // a Google LatLng object
    this.nelatlon = new google.maps.LatLng( splitBox[7], splitBox[8]);    // a Google LatLng object
    this.points   = [this.swlatlon, this.selatlon, this.nwlatlon, this.nelatlon] //store all points for easy access
    this.count    = count;         // number of ships in this box

    //calculate center of this box
    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(this.swlatlon, this.nelatlon);
    this.center = this.bounds.getCenter();
    this.weightedLocation = { location : this.center, weight : this.count }; // <-- object created here
}
```

**Where the objects are pushed into an array**

```
function parseJsonForModelData(json, datatype) {
    for(index in json) {
            obj = json[index];

            if (index == "Model Data") 
            {
                $j.each(obj, function(k, v) 
                {
                    if (datatype == 'heat') 
                    {
                        box = new Box(k, v);

                        // Check boxNumber.  If null, skip messes up world map!
                        if (box.boxNumber == 'null') 
                        {
                            badDataCnt++;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            modelData.push(box.weightedLocation); <<- pushed here
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
return modelData;
}
```

**WeightedLocations**

```
327: {"location":{"$a":-35.5,"ab":172},"weight":"11"} object music.js:730
328: {"location":{"$a":-36.5,"ab":151},"weight":"1"} object music.js:730
329: {"location":{"$a":-37.5,"ab":151},"weight":"1"} object music.js:730
330: {"location":{"$a":-37.5,"ab":168},"weight":"3"} object music.js:730
331: {"location":{"$a":-37.5,"ab":169},"weight":"6"} object music.js:730
332: {"location":{"$a":-39.5,"ab":161},"weight":"4"} object music.js:730
333: {"location":{"$a":-39.5,"ab":162},"weight":"5"} object music.js:730
334: {"location":{"$a":-39.5,"ab":165},"weight":"6"} object music.js:730
```

Comment: Can you post the code which generate this error please ?

Comment: @Corum Sure thing, the bottommost line is what causes the error. When I remove the last element of the array that is supposedly invalid the error just moves to the next to last one.

Comment: I don't know very well this part of Google Maps API, but I think you don't have to encapsulate your `heatMapOptions` object into another. Try instead : `new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer(heatMapOptions)`.

Comment: hmm That also causes the same error to be thrown, thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: OK. I confirm what I have saied about encapsulating. Here is the official documentation : [Google Maps API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers). Have you tried to remove options (one by one) from `heatMapOptions` to know if error come from here ?

Comment: No I hadn't thought to try that because when I hardcoded an example everything worked perfectly. The only difference is the array is now generated by a function instead of by hand.

Comment: Can you post function which now generate your JS object ?

Comment: @Corum It gets created in the Box constructor then pushed into an array and returned to the function that creates the heat map

Comment: Try to add `console.log(weightedLocations);` in your code, and check in Firebug if all your LatLng Objects are correctly initialized.

Comment: All of the objects have all their fields, that was one of the first things I looked at. I will post a small cut out above.

Comment: Since the question is a bit long I thought I'd ask if it's been resolved yet. If not, I'll try replicating it on my end (I haven't tried the Heatmap layers and it looks like a cool thing to learn).

Comment: No I am still working on it, I also have a thread going on the google groups page for the visualization api. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/google-maps-js-api-v3/WeightedLocation/google-maps-js-api-v3/6loiXM3i-Pg/y5DzaQIsShsJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed the WeightedLocations you posted has strings for weight. When testing with hardcoded data, I did run into problems when `weight` is a string, so try using parseInt/float inside the `function Box`, hopefully this will make things work.

Comment: The output is a string because I am using JSON.stringify(object) to easily dump my objects to the console. I am using integers for the weights.

Comment: I calculate the weight as a number, but for some reason it was converted to a string, I didn't notice until you said something. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, glad we found the cause :) About the stringify, shouldn't it preserve the type of the value? Or is it browser-dependent (this would be bad)? [**here's a jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DRHvr/)

Comment: I made the assumption that stringify would turn the object into a JSON string with all the properties as strings also. But my browser also maintained numeric types throughout the call. Thanks for that too. :)